# Why does this rust code hang when there is no file, but runs fine when the file exists?

Tags: rust, file-io, filesystems

I have some rust code to read lines from a file, and then print them. It creates a file if the specified file name does not exist. It exits fine if the file exists, and reads the lines, but if the file does not exist, it creates the file, and just does nothing. The program does not exit if the file does not exist.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::io::ErrorKind;

fn file_to_vec(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> { 
    let file_in = File::open(filename);
    let file_in = match file_in {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(error) => match error.kind() {
            ErrorKind::NotFound => match File::create(filename) {
                Ok(file) => {println!("Created file: {}", filename); file},
                Err(e) => panic!("Problem creating the file: {:?}", e),
            },
            other_error => {
                panic!("Problem opening the file: {:?}", other_error)
            }
        },
    };
    let file_reader = io::BufReader::new(file_in); 
    file_reader.lines().filter_map(io::Result::ok).collect()
} 


fn main() {
    let stuff = file_to_vec("stuff.txt");
    for thing in stuff {
        println!("{}", thing)
    }
}
```

Comment: My suspicion is that since File::create creates a file in write only mode, you’re hitting this issue when trying to read it; https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34703

Comment: `filter_map(Result::ok)` is an anti-pattern because it _hides_ errors, i.e. lets them pass silently, equivalent to something like `try { ... } catch (Exception e) {}` in Java. Since you panic in other places, you could change it to `map(Result::unwrap)`, and you'll observe the actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `File::create` opens a file without `read` flag so it cannot be read.

I fixed it using `OpenOptions`:

```rust
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use std::io::ErrorKind;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn file_to_vec(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let file_in = File::open(filename);
    let file_in = match file_in {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(error) => match error.kind() {
            ErrorKind::NotFound => {
                let mut options = OpenOptions::new();
                options.read(true).write(true).create(true);
                match options.open(filename) {
                    Ok(file) => {
                        println!("Created file: {}", filename);
                        file
                    }
                    Err(e) => panic!("Problem creating the file: {:?}", e),
                }
            }
            other_error => {
                panic!("Problem opening the file: {:?}", other_error)
            }
        },
    };
    let file_reader = io::BufReader::new(file_in);
    file_reader.lines().map(Result::unwrap).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let stuff = file_to_vec("stuff.txt");
    for thing in stuff {
        println!("{}", thing)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you even need `write(true)` in the options - perhaps `read(true).create(true)` would be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, probably, this is enough.